# Merging PowerPoint presentations using Apache-POI doesn't work well with charts

Tags: merge, apache-poi, powerpoint

We have a single page presentations (*.pptx) and we would like to combine them into a single presentation. Trying to follow the cookbook solution from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_ppt/apache_poi_ppt_merging.htm
didn't work. It always creates a ppt that requires repair and never had the chart.

To recreate this simply create two one page presentations with a chart and place it in a folder

```
    File folder = new File("<myFolder_path>");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    //creating empty presentation
    XMLSlideShow presentation = new XMLSlideShow();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

        File currentFile = listOfFiles[i];
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
        XMLSlideShow src = new XMLSlideShow(inputstream);
        inputstream.close();
        for (XSLFSlide srcSlide : src.getSlides()) {
            XSLFSlide newSlide = presentation.createSlide();
            newSlide.importContent(srcSlide);
        }

    }

    File pptxFile = File.createTempFile("xxx" + "_", ".pptx");

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pptxFile);
    presentation.write(out);
    out.close();
```

Comment: There are many things [XSLFSlide.importContent](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlide.html#importContent-org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet-) not takes into account, as you even see in your linked tutorialspoint example (background images are lost, some font settings differs, ...). But at least using `apache poi 4.0.1` the charts **are** taken into account. But I have never understood why the requirement to merge Office documents together matters. Why not simply creating the needed result at once?

Comment: Thank you @AxelRichter for your quick response. The reason we bother with merging presentations is because we get out of memory exception when producing the large presentations. The logic was to divide the process into two phases. In the 1st phase create small presentations, and in the 2nd phase merge them together.

Comment: How do you think the merging solves the out-of-memory-problem? After `XMLSlideShow presentation = new XMLSlideShow();` the target `presentation` also needs to be fully in memory **additional** to each single `XMLSlideShow src` until the GC destroys them.

Comment: During the process of the slide show creation there are other variables that consume significant amount of memory. That why we thought this method will help. Regardless to our out of memory issue, I just wanted to know if I was doing something wrong in the merging process. From your answer, it seems that the merging feature is incomplete.

Comment: "the merging feature is incomplete": Right. And I doubt it will be complete sometime. At least not in terms of "do providing merging any PPTX with any other PPTX just like PowerPoint is able to do by copy/paste". The internally structures are too complex, there are too many edge cases and the Microsoft PowerPoint development ptocess is so advanced that you can not reach it anymore in it's entirety.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge presentations with Aspose.Slides for .NET. [There is a related article.](https://docs.aspose.com/display/slidesnet/Merge+Presentation)

```
var presentation1 = new Presentation("presentation1.pptx");
var presentation2 = new Presentation("presentation2.pptx");
foreach (var slide in presentation2.Slides)
{
    presentation1.Slides.AddClone(slide);
}
presentation1.Save("presentation_merged.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

Comment: There are 100 free calls using Aspose.Slides API. They also offer a free [web app](https://products.aspose.app/slides/merger).